# coloring cube sides and vertices

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

In how many rotational distinct ways can we color the vertices of a cube with 2 colors and faces with 4 colors? (This can be interpreted in two ways, either you have to use exactly 4 colors or at most 4. I'm interested in solving it for both conditions).

There are questions and answers for each part separately but I couldn't find a wholesome answer on each part (either coloring only faces or only vertices) also I don't know how to join the two answers.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Dzoooks thanks I edited the question, rotational distinct means if you count a cube in your answer there shouldn't be another one counted if the two can turn into each other  by rotation (for example front side red and the rest blue vs. back side red and the rest blue), Also I'm not sure that the two (faces and vertices) are separate, you may be right but it's not that obvious to me

Comment: @Dzoooks No, you can't count vertex colorings and face colorings separately and multiply the numbers. For instance, if there is just one red vertex and just one red face, we can distinguish between colorings where the red vertex is on the red face and colorings where it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mixed cycle index  for faces and vertices combined can  be of use in
this problem.  We can  then apply  Burnside or  Polya as  desired. The
group  $H$  here are  the  rotations  permuting  six faces  and  eight
vertices simultanteously, acting on fourteen  slots for the colors. We
use $b_q$ for the cycles of the vertices and $a_q$ for the faces.

We proceed to  enumerate the permutations of this group.  There is the
identity, which  contributes $$a_1^6 b_1^8.$$

There are  three rotations for  each pair  of opposite faces  that fix
those faces (rotate  about the axis passing through the  center of the
two  faces). The  vertices  on the  two faces  are  in four-cycles  or
two-cycles, for a contribution of

$$3\times (2 a_1^2 a_4 b_4^2 + a_1^2 a_2^2 b_2^4).$$

There are rotations  about an axis passing  through opposite vertices,
of which  there are four pairs.  These fix those vertices  and put the
rest on three-cycles, giving

$$4\times 2 a_3^2 b_1^2 b_3^2.$$

Finally we  may rotate about  an axis  passing through the  centers of
opposite edges and  there are six of these.  These rotations partition
the vertices into two-cycles, giving

$$6\times a_2^3 b_2^4.$$

It follows that the cycle index of $H$ is given by

$$Z(H) = \frac{1}{24} 
\left(a_1^6 b_1^8 
+ 6 a_1^2 a_4 b_4^2 
+ 3 a_1^2 a_2^2 b_2^4  
+ 8 a_3^2 b_1^2 b_3^2 
+ 6 a_2^3 b_2^4\right).$$

Using at most $N$ colors for the faces and $M$ for the vertices we get
for the number of colorings by Burnside

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
H(N, M) = \frac{1}{24}(N^6 M^8 + 6 N^3 M^2 
+ 3 N^4 M^4 + 8 N^2 M^4 + 6 N^3 M^4).}$$

Setting $M=1$ here we should get face colorings. We obtain a polynomial in $N$:

$$1, 10, 57, 240, 800, 2226, 5390, 11712, \ldots$$

and we encounter [OEIS A047780](https://oeis.org/A047780) where we see that
we have the right values. Setting $N=1$ yields vertex colorings. We obtain a polynomial in $M$:

$$1, 23, 333, 2916, 16725, 70911, 241913, 701968, \ldots$$

which  points  to  [OEIS A000543](https://oeis.org/A000543)  which  is
correct as well.

Continuing with the question of  colorings that use exactly $N$ colors
for the faces and exactly $M$ for the vertices we find using Stirling numbers
for set partitions

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{gather} H_X(N, M) = \frac{N! \times M!}{24}
\\ \times \left({6\brace N} {8\brace M} 
+ 6 {3\brace N} {2\brace M}
+ 3 {4\brace N} {4\brace M} 
+ 8 {2\brace N} {4\brace M} 
+ 6 {3\brace N} {4\brace M}\right).
\end{gather}}$$

Setting $M=1$ here we get the count of face colorings with exactly $N$
colors:

$$1, 8, 30, 68, 75, 30, 0, \ldots$$

Note that for  six colors, which is the maximum,  the orbits have size
$24$ because  all the  colors are  distinct and  indeed $6!/24  = 30.$
Similarly with $N=1$ we get vertex colorings:

$$1, 21, 267, 1718, 5250, 7980, 5880, 1680, 0, \ldots$$

and once  more for eight  colors, the  maximum possible, we  find that
$8!/24 = 1680.$

Concluding we get for at most two  vertex colors and at most four face
colors

$$H(4,2) = 44608$$

and for exactly two vertex colors and four face colors

$$H_X(4,2) = 16552.$$

Comment: **NOTE:** The sequence $1,10,57,240,...$ is for $N$ , the other $1,23,333,...$ is for $M$

Comment: Well isn't that right, we set $M=1$ to get the first sequence which is dependent on $N$ and similarly for $N=1$ we get the sequence in $M.$

Comment: i think you made a typo there , you wrote M in place of N ,and vice versa.For example try for $M=2$

Comment: The sequences match the OEIS entries.

Answer (score 0):

We have to write some cycle indices. By Maple, the two permutation groups are 6T8 and 8T14.

For G acting on faces we have :
${1 \over 24 } (x_1^6 + 3.x_1^2x_2^2  + 6x_2^3+ 6x_1^2x_4 + 8.x_3^2 )$

For G acting on vertices we have :
${1 \over 24 } (y_1^8 + 3.y_2^4 + 6.y_2^4 + 6.y_4^2 + 8.y_1^2.y_3^2 )$

For G acting on both, the cycle index is

${1 \over 24 } (x_1^6y_1^8 + 3x_1^2x_2^2y_1^8  + 6x_2^3y_2^4+ 6x_1^2x_4y_4^2 + 8x_3^2y_1^2y_3^2 )$

Polya method means essentially to associate a 'colored permutation' to a colored partition, establishing a one-to-one correspondence between colored permutations and fixed points.

e.g. $ \color {red} {(A)}  \color {green} {(B)} \color {blue} {(C)} \color {green} {(D , E, F)} $  is associated  to a colored partition $ \color {red} A \ | \color {green}  {B, D, E, F}  \ | \ \color {blue} C\  $

Since the sets of faces and vertices do not overlap, neither do the cycles that form a "colored permutation". We may safely count them using the multiplication principle.
Thus, passing to m and n we get

${1 \over 24 } (m^6n^8 + 3m^4n^4 + 6 m^3n^4 + 6m^3n^2 +8m^2n^4)$

Eventually we obtain a generating function like

$AtMost(x) = 0 + x + 10x^2 + 57x^3 +240x^4 + 800x^5 + 2226x^6 +5390x^7+ \cdots$

when we still need

$Exact(x) = 0 + x + 8x^2 + 30x^3 + 68x^4 + 75x^5 + 30x^6 + 0 + 0 + \cdots$

The two GF's are related. For example, $57 = {3\choose 3}30 + {3\choose 2}8 + {3\choose 1} 1 + {3\choose 0}0 $ meaning that at most three colors are obtained adding configurations of actually three colors to configurations having pairs of colors and so on.

Reversely, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $Exact$ g.f. is extracted from $AtMost$
by
$coeff \ ( \ Exact(x), x^k \ ) \ = coeff \ ( \ AtMost(x)(1-x)^k \ ) $

Within respect with the previous studied example $H(4,2)$, taken into account both variables

"at most" $0, 23, 776, 8121, 44608$ produce "exact" values $0, 23, 730, 5863, 16688$

"at most" $0, 1, 10, 57, 240$ produce "exact" values $0, 8 , 30 , 68$

Then we extract the exact value $H_X(4,2) = 16552 = 16688 - 2\times68$